# What does '@comment()' do in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have been working on an XPath parser, with the grammars [here](http://www.w3.org/2013/01/qt-applets/xpath1/) as a reference. I was surpised that an `@` symbol with a `KindTest` is possible. The `KindTest` can be `node()`, `comment()`, `text()`, or `processing-instruction(xyz)` (they test for the [Node Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256176.aspx)).

My question is what these do when combined with an `@` sign; . What do `@processing-instruction("xyz")`,  `@comment()`, `@node`, and `@text` do? Are they searching for attributes with processing instructions or comments in them?

Comment: I'm curious why you're writing an XPath parser? Sounds like fun ... :-)

Comment: ... A little bit of both :) and :(, heh. I'm converting ITS-decorated XML documents into HTML, and the ITS has to stay, but the HTML has to be completely legal. I'm required to change the names of all of the nodes in the document, and also get rid of most attributes, but all of the XPaths in the ITS still have to work, meaning they need to be edited to match the new nodes. I decided that a bunch of regexes wouldn't have enough coverage, and I wouldn't know enough about XPath to make them unless I looked at the full grammar specification anyway.

Comment: Wow ... automatically editing XPath expressions to match a transformed document. I hadn't heard of people trying to do that before. I guess if the nodes that are left still have the same hierarchical relationships, it wouldn't be too hard ... provided the XPath expressions aren't too dependent on the nodes being removed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually thinking that doing it this way was a Bad Idea (though writing a parser was fun). It'd be much easier to evaluate the XPath on the document, give each matching element a unique ID, and just replace the XPath with a match on all of those IDs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@comment()` is a valid XPath location path step expression that is guaranteed to return nothing.  Technically it is asking for all comment nodes found along the attribute axis (and you will never find any).

I tell my students that `/..` is a more compact and readable way of writing a complete location path that is guaranteed to return nothing.  Technically it is asking for the parent of the root node.

Comment: Why is it even built into the grammar if it is guaranteed to return nothing?

Comment: The grammar is already there for other uses. No need to explicitly deny this possibility.

Comment: The designers of the language chose to keep the axis and the NodeTest orthogonal even though there are combinations of axis and node kind that cannot occur in practice. Orthogonality is considered an asset in language design but one could argue either way; Saxon issues a warning for such cases. The danger if you start banning things that aren't useful is "paternalism" - you stop people writing things like `xx[true()]` or `$x+0`, not because they aren't well defined, but because you can't see any reason why anyone would want to write such a thing.

Answer (score 7):

NateGlenn, it's not that `@comment()` is built into the grammar. It's just that the combination of `@` and `comment()` isn't specially forbidden.

As you may know, `@` is just an abbreviation for the `attribute::` axis. Axes are built into the grammar. Node tests (like `node()` and `comment()`) are built into a separate part of the grammar.

In order for the combination `@comment()` to be forbidden by the grammar, there would have to be a special case. You can think of other combinations that don't make much sense except to return an empty nodeset: `parent::text()`, for example.

It's rather like expecting `1 / 0` or `sqrt(-1)` to be forbidden by the grammar of C.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't realize `@` was short for `attribute::`. The grammar from W3c [here](http://www.w3.org/2013/01/qt-applets/xpath1/jjdoc.html) gives `AbbrevForwardStep ::= ( "@" )? NodeTest`, which I thought would have been better as `AbbrevForwardStep ::= ( "@" )? NameTest`. Since it's just an abbreviation for `attribute::`, I can see why they did it that way.

Comment: @NateGlenn: good point. I didn't realize (or had forgotten) that grammar put `@` in a separate rule from the unabbreviated axes. But consider if they had said `AbbrevForwardStep ::= ( "@" )? NameTest`. Then you couldn't have `@comment()`, but you could still have `attribute::comment()`. That would be a strange asymmetry. You would also lose the ability to say `@node()`, which is a more useful construction (although, AFAICT, it's equivalent to `@*`, which you wouldn't lose).

Comment: If AbbrevForwardStep had been defined with NameTest instead of NodeTest, you'd lose not only `@comment()` but also `comment()` (the short-form for `child::comment()`) and all abbreviated tests on the child axis that aren't node tests.  One reason to treat orthogonality as if it were an end in itself is to avoid such unintentional collateral damage when making changes to grammars.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen: Good point ... I didn't catch the fact that `AbbrevForwardStep` handles not only the abbreviated `attribute` axis but also the abbreviated `child` axis.